# Passing an error message from controller to view with Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the following error message available as HTML:

```
<div class="alert alert-error">
    <div class="content">
        <p>
             <i class="fa fa-warning"></i>
            User not found.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I display it for the user **without** losing good practices, in Backbone?

I mean, what's the best way to make my view render it with reliability?

### When is this message  displayed?

```
user.save({}, {
  success: function(model, response) {
    if (response.error) {
      // hey, the message goes here!
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend Backbone View with a new method to display errors like this :

```
_.extend(Backbone.View.prototype, {
    showError: function(message) {
        // Here you render your error, may be like this : $('#errorInfo').html(message);
    }
});
```

and in your view :

```
var self = this; // I assume that you are in the view
user.save({}, {
  success: function(model, response) {
    if (response.error) {
      self.showError(/* things you want to pass */);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: `_.extend(...` and that's all? In the same file of my view? I think a view exclusively for errors is a good thing.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge yes `_.extend(...` and that's all, you can place it where you have placed `Backbone.History.start(...` to be sure that all views will have this new function. A Backbone View is meant to interact with models/collections and events, if you use it the way you want to, it's like use it as a template and it's not meant for that

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge So, have you tried this solution ?

Answer (score 1):

For me the best practice is to create an object *errorMessageView*

HTML :

```
<div id="errorInfo"></div>
```

JS :

```
var errorMessageView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#errorInfo",
    initialize: function() {
    },
    renderInnerHTML: function(message) {
            this.el.innerHTML = message;
    }
});

var errorMessage = new errorMessageView ;

user.save({}, {
    success: function(model, response) {
      if (response.error) {
        errorMessage.renderInnerHTML(response.error);
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: That's not the point. I know how to render technically, but I don't think that rendering that message through Backbone is a good practice. It is? It's the best way?